# Вырезать элемент и обернуть им содержимое , в котором он находился jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

С этого:

```
<div> <a href="#"></a> </div>
```

Надо сделать вот так:

```
<a href="#"><div></div></a>
```

Были попытки взять этот элемент и методом wrap запихнуть в него содержимое, но есть одно но: таких вот блоков несколько штук

```
<div> <a href="#1"></a> </div>
<div> <a href="#2"></a> </div>
<div> <a href="#3"></a> </div>
```

и нужно чтоб сохранялись ссылки для каждого

Comment: А почему бы не верстать сразу так как требуется, зачем делать сначала не так, а потом скриптом править?

Comment: @yolosora это подключаемый модуль Joomla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прогоняете цикл `each` для всех для вложенных элементов. А в цикле запоминаете родителя и вызывайте `unwrap`/`wrapInner(parent)`

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('div > a').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var parent = el.parent();
    el.unwrap().wrapInner(parent);
  });
  console.log($('#content').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div class="a1"> <a href="#1"></a> </div>
  <div class="a2"> <a href="#2"></a> </div>
  <div class="a3"> <a href="#3"></a> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AntonShchyriv а если у каждого дива свой класс, можно ли как-то и его сохранить?

Comment: @CTACO23 Укажите в вопросе реальную разметку